# Centralizer of projections

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, compact-operators, projection

Let $H$ be a *Hilbert space* and $p, q$ self-adjoint projectors in $B(H)$,
 i.e. $$p^2=p=p^* \space \text{ and } \space q^2=q=q^*.$$ Suppose they have the same centralizers $C(p)=C(q)$.
 Is it true that $p=\pm q$?
 Here $C(x)=\{y\in B(H) : yx=xy\}$.
Maybe I am asking a well known result but I couldn't find anything about this problem in the literature.

Comment: I think you want to say "Is it true that $p = 1 - q$ or $p = q$". Minus a projection is not a projection.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Vaughan Jones notes, Exerise 2.1.13. $A$ and $A^\ast$ preserve a subspace $K$, ie $A K \subset K$ and $A^\ast K \subset K$ iff $[A,P_K] = 0$, where $P_K$ is the orthogonal projection onto $K$.